# oracle - concatenate in select for drop, create, grant - lost in ''''

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, concatenation

I am new to Oracle database, got a task to write several selects, but I do not get somethow principle, how it works (or better to say does not work). Could you please help me to find a mistake and probably you have a link to some info or converter that helps such writings.

```
v_sql := 'SELECT ''DROP TABLE ''||object_name||'' as
            select *  
            FROM all_objects
            WHERE object_name LIKE '''%''|| v_date ||''%'''
            and object_type = ''TABLE''
            and owner =''||v_owner||''';
```

Comment: I find your comment erogant. It is not my business logic. I am trying to achieve concatenation and fail. it is not a reason to mark my question and answers of users with -2 points. When you shifted from history (as it is written in your prifile) you were not better, I am sure as me, when I just shifted from biology. How can I ask without showing an example?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to generate `DROP` statements for a specific user?  Start with the below anonymous block and add to it.

```
--Generate DROP statements for all tables for a user.
declare
    v_owner varchar2(128) := user;
begin
    for objects in
    (
        select distinct 'DROP TABLE "'||owner||'"."'||object_name||'"' v_sql
        from all_objects
        where object_type = 'TABLE'
            and owner = v_owner
        order by v_sql
    ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(objects.v_sql);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: declare
    v_owner varchar2(130) := 'ORA1';
    v_date varchar2(130) := 'LOYEE';
begin
    for objects in
    (
        select distinct 'DROP TABLE '||owner||'.'||object_name||'' v_sql
        from all_objects
        where object_type = 'TABLE'
            and object_name LIKE 'EMP'||v_date||'' 
            and owner = v_owner
        order by v_sql
    ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(objects.v_sql);
    end loop;
end;
/

Comment: how do I have format of the code like you not a like like mines?

Comment: @Viola_M I'm not sure what exactly where the issue is.  It might be around the `LIKE 'EMP'` part, which should probably have a `%` wildcard.  Part of the issue is that your statement is doing three distinct things, and doing them all at once it's easy to get confused.  Break the problem into three parts.  First, build a query that returns the relevant tables.  Don't use variables, hard-code everything.  Second, convert the query into a query that generates a `DROP` statement.  Finally, put that query in a PL/SQL block to iterate through the results, and use variables instead of hard-coding.

Comment: Jon, why do you have in your code '' around these words? is it necessary? Or I can omit this ''. See what I get as output: DROP TABLE "ORA1"."LOCATIONS"
DROP TABLE "ORA1"."MY_EMPLOYEE"
DROP TABLE "ORA1"."REGIONS"

Comment: @Viola_M It's only necessary if your schema contains case-sensitive table names.  Which is unlikely, but just in case it might be worth coding for it ahead of time.  If you're sure the code will not be used against case-sensitive names then it's fine to exclude the quotation marks.